Angels creation and free will
Where does the belief come from that angels have no free will? I have searched the scriptures and find nothing that speaks to this. Is it a belief that has entered through commentaries or traditions? There is no mention in the Scriptures that God created angels either, so how do we just accept that?

The Talmud in tractate Shabbat 89a relates the background story when Moshe was on Har Sinai that the angels were complaining and saying that they should receive the Torah and Gd tells Moshe to relate to them why they should not get the Torah and the Jewish nation should. I’ve cited the relevant point below in which Moshe says that they do not have an evil inclination (and thus free will)

…Again Moses asked: What else is written in it? God said to him: “You
shall not murder, you shall not commit adultery, you shall not steal”
(Exodus 20:13) Moses asked the angels: Is there jealousy among you, or
is there an evil inclination within you that would render these
commandments relevant? Immediately they agreed with the Holy One,
Blessed be He, that He made the right decision to give the Torah to
the people, and as it is stated: “God our Lord, how glorious is Your
name in all the earth” (Psalms 8:10), while “that Your majesty is
placed above the heavens” is not written because the angels agreed
with God that it is appropriate to give the Torah to the people on
earth.

We can see here proof for both points you questioned. The first, that yes Gd did create angels. The second, they do not have free will since Moshes argument as to why they should not receive the Torah is because they do not have an evil inclination, and without an evil inclination you do not have free will
Hope that helps!


The Tanach, unlike the New Testament and other religious books, almost never concerns itself with anything beyond the sphere of human experience, including things pertaining to heaven and the afterlife.
The angels' creation therefore is captured in the statement "And God created the heavens and...". Angels are heavenly beings, so were created when the heavens were (although Bereshit Rabbah records a tradition that they were only created on the second day, or perhaps the fifth day, in order to prevent people from claiming Hashem needed help creating the world).
We are not allowed to pray to angels, e.g. Exodus 20:4. It's hard to fathom how someone could possibly argue that this is not one of, if not the major theme of the Torah - it is a mistake to bow to idols of any kind, even if you still believe in God etc.
The reason we do not bow down to idols is because they do not have free will*. This is considered one of the main errors regarding idols - eyes but can't see, ears but can't hear etc.
We also note that the only arena in which free will can take place is with regards to right and wrong, i.e. the Mitzvot. The Mitzvot were only given to mankind. No Mitzvot are given to angels, nowhere in the Torah does Hashem address Himself to angels.
We can therefore see that it's very clear in the Torah that angels don't have "free" will. They cannot abandon their mission (and of course, there isn't a single example or hint anywhere in Torah of an angel abandoning its mission). They may have will, and consciousness (and are likely so esoteric that we cannot fathom their existence and being anyway so let's not speculate any further), but it's clear that it's not free.
Can there be exceptions to this? Of course. We do have traditions of angels Hashem gave free will to as a test, and they failed. Hashem can do anything He likes, this answer is just general.
Finally, that point about tradition. Please note that this is Mi Yodeya and it is highly unusual here to ask for an only-Scripture-based answer. As I wrote here (and strongly recommend you read the first part), Scripture was never meant to be standalone. Torah is supposed to be interpreted with the commentary that God gave at Sinai, and gave authority to the Sages to preserve, involve themselves with, and even develop (which they have done so so well, you'll be amazed if you take the time to look into it). See this answer for more on that and feel free to ask any questions.

Of course, the "things the Tanach doesn't concern itself with" (see point 1) will be found in this rich tradition, and this is why it's completely fair we give you an answer from the Gemara, although I hope you have enjoyed the arguments I've made from simple analysis of the Tanach in this one case.
* This is one of several reasons, but I will not get into the whole subject here

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
